# m4 does not parse local variables

Tags: c, m4

I have a problem with an m4 macro. The macro is

```
define(BARRIER, `
#if defined USE_PTHREAD_BARRIERS
barrier_wait(&$1,$2,$3);
#elif defined (USE_CENTRALIZED_BARRIERS)
central_barrier(&$1,$2,$3);
#endif
')
```

and in my .C file i have

`BARRIER(Global->start, P, MyNum)` where `Global->start` and `P` are globals and MyNum a local variable.

But when I execute

```
m4 macrosfile.m4 sourcefile > outputfile
```

in the output file there is this:

```
#if defined USE_PTHREAD_BARRIERS
barrier_wait(&Global->start,P,);
#elif defined (USE_CENTRALIZED_BARRIERS)
central_barrier(&Global->start,P,);
```

Something wrong with my macro, or just a limitation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `m4` as a preprocessor to C? Up to my knowledge C has a buildin preprocessor no ?-)

Comment: @JensGustedt yes i Know that, but with this way use can reuse same macros in different programs-projects. Also I am forced to do that way...

Comment: The backticks/apostrophe quoting are actually a good choice, since backticks are unlikely to appear in code.  As a result, you can often use m4 to translate source code with no changes.  (And of course, if you need a different quote character, m4 allows that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing:

```
BARRIER(Global->start, P, MyNum)
```

to:

```
BARRIER(`Global->start', `P', `MyNum')
```

As for me, I'd try and avoid m4 by using an [X-Macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) or something like it:

```
#if defined USE_PTHREAD_BARRIERS
#define BARRIER_X(x_, y_, z_) barrier_wait(&x_, y_, z_)
#elif defined (USE_CENTRALIZED_BARRIERS)
#define BARRIER_X(x_, y_, z_) central_barrier(&x_, y_, z_)
#endif
```

...

```
BARRIER_X(Global->start, P, MyNum);
```